# Ajax/cakephp 2. Click into one checkbox, and populate two different select boxes

Tags: jquery, cakephp-2.5

I´m trying to click into one checkbox and populate two diferent select boxes.

I have to populate the brand select box and the model select box.

If the given car is the same car from the last visit for a given client person, returning into an car repair shop.

My starting point is the jquery ajax below.

But it is created to populate just one select box.

I trying to figure out how to populate the two diferent select boxes, after clicking into just one checkbox.

checkbox id:            sameCarFromLastVisit
brand select box id :   brandId
model select box id :   modelId

For the backend i am using cakephp 2.

How can it be done ?

```
$(function(){

    $(document).on('click', "#sameCarFromLastVisit", function()
    {
        var url = '<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'Cars', 'action' => 'getBrandModel_ajax')); ?>';
        var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
        var data = {
            checked: $(this).val()
        };

        $.ajax({

            url: url,
            method: 'POST',
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',

            beforeSend: function( xhr ) 
            {
                if(checked == 1){

                    $.blockUI({
                        message: '<h2>Please wait! searching brand and Model</h2>'
                    });

                }

            },
            complete: function () 
            {
                $.unblockUI();
            },
            success: function ($response, a, b) 
            {
                if(b.status == 200) 
                {
                    var $optionsBrand = $("#brandId").html($("<option />").val('').text('- selecione -'));

                    if($response)
                    {
                        console.log('response '+$response);
                        $optionsBrand.prop("disabled", false);

                        $.each($response, function(idbrand, value)
                        {
                            var $opt = new Option(value, idbrand);

                            $optionsBrand.append($opt);
                        });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $optionsBrand.prop("disabled", true);
                    }

                }
                else 
                {
                    alert($response);
                }
            },
            error: function(x, t, m) 
            {
                var msg = 'An unexpected error occur. ';

                if( t === "timeout" )
                {
                    msg += "wait 30 segundos and try again!";
                }
                else
                {
                    msg = t;
                }

                alert( msg );
            }
        }); //ajax
    }); // document on 'click'

}); // function
```

Comment: I assume the two select boxes depend on each other? i.e. what's in the model box depends on what's in the brand box? If so, then search on google about "cascading dropdowns"

Comment: Hi!, no, in this particular case the two are not necessarily dependent, but yes the model belongs to the brand. But the point is to recover the last two informations: brand and model for the last visit of the car into the auto repair office.